# npm start assertionError

Tags: git, npm, terminal, gulp

I am trying to use getbase.org css framework for my new project:

They have an installation setup on their documentation which is:

git clone https://github.com/matthewhartman/base-starter.git your-website /
&& cd your-website && rm -rf .git && npm i && npm start

This is what I get when I want to start it, I do have the latest node, npm and gulp installed:

[image]

[image]

Also I just realise that project version is 3.9.1 but local version is 4.0.0, maybe that's the case? I have used getbase.org without any problems before i reinstalled my ubuntu os.

Any help is appreaciated, been looking for a solution for hours... 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Difference between CLI and local was the problem, I had to run sudo npm install gulp@3.9.1 --save and now it works just fine...